# How to use chmod to change a file's permission?

Tags: php, unix, chmod

I used `ls -l` to find file permissions in a shell and found this:

File 1: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 451 Mar  9 15:25 file.class.php`

File 2: `-rw-rw-r-- 1 andy dev 872 Mar  9 15:43 file.class.php`

I want file 1's permissions to be changed to file 2's permissions. I have root access and am `cd'd` to the proper directories. I have never used chmod before and am having some trouble. When I try to do this:

`chmod 872 file.clas.php`

I get the error: `chmod: invalid mode: '872'`

Comment: 0664, or just `chmod g+w`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That 5th column is the filesize, not the permissions. The permissions are listed on the left in expanded form. The permissions on the first file are 644 in octal (add up the contributions from each bit: r-- = 4, -w- = 2, --x = 1, so rw- = 6), and the permissions on the second file are 664. Therefore, you want

```
chmod 664 file.class.php
```

---

Alternately, remember that the three permission groups are *user*, *group* and *other*, so `rw-rw-r--` is "user rw, group rw, other r". Then, to change `rw-r--r--` into `rw-rw-r--`, you need to add group-write permissions, i.e.

```
chmod g+w file.class.php
```

This lets you update the permissions individually.

Comment: Hmm. The permissions changed successfully but I still can't seem to save the file while connected to the server in Notepad++. It's located on a server and I created it with a root account instead of a user account and even with the different permissions the upload is failing. Any idea what it might be? Are there other permissions I could change?

Comment: The 3rd and 4th columns are the *user* and *group* who *own* the file. The first file is owned by `root:root` and the second file by `andy:dev`. So, you want to *change the owner* of the first file to `andy:dev`: `chown andy:dev file.class.php`